# Java Sorting alphabet and get position number

Tags: java, sorting

I written the following code with the output 'act', i would like to convert this into number 'a' to 1 and 'c' to 2 and 't' to 3.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1 = "cat";
    char[] arr;
    arr = s1.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    s1 = new String(arr);
    System.out.println(s1);

}
```

output

```
act
```

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. Please try to post an specific question.

Comment: u have poor understanding then =D

Comment: Come on, help us to help you!

Comment: I think the issue here is the fact that there isn't much information provided.

Comment: @user3171818 No, you have a poor question. If I were to take a shot at this, I would say `int i = 123;` What's so hard about that?

Comment: R.J got my question and answered.

Comment: what the question is ?

Comment: I could have guessed what the question was, but is not better to ask before posting an answer? Just to be sure.

Comment: @user3171818 this is outright rude. I think Christian was wanting to help you and asking you for being more specific. And i agree, the question isnt completely clear. well, not that it bothers me. you might get lesser help if you arent clear and concise

Comment: I cant think of a better way to phrase this question.
I given enough outline in the title and also providing example in the question .

Comment: The title is "Java Sorting alphabet and get position number". I don't think the question is about sorting, that's just unuseful information. Also you could have posted an output example (of the "question").

Comment: ok..I will provide example of the question. I will learn frm mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sorting the array, you can simple iterate through each of the array elements and print out the index for each of them.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i] + " is at the position " + (i + 1));
}
```

Note that you need to use `i + 1` since arrays have *0-based* index.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ascii values

```
public class Ssort 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1=s.nextLine();
        String s2=s1.toLowerCase();
        char []a=s2.toCharArray();
        int h,g = 0,l=0;
        int b=(int)a[0];
        System.out.println();
        for(int k=0;k<a.length;k++)
        {
            for(h=1+k;h<a.length;h++)
            {
                if(b>(int)a[h])
                {   
                    b=a[h];
                    char temp=a[h];
                    a[h]=a[k];
                    a[k]=temp;
                }

            }
        if(l<a.length-1)
        {
                b=a[++l];
        }
        }

        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[j]);
        }
    }

}
```

using alphabet to sort

```
public class Hi1 {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s1,s3;
        java.lang.String s2;
        int i,j;
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        s1=s.nextLine();
        s2="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        s3=s1.toLowerCase();
        char [] c=s3.toCharArray();
        char [] c1=s2.toCharArray();
        for(i=0;i<c1.length;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c.length;j++)
            {
                if(c1[i]==c[j])
                {
                    System.out.print(c[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(c[0]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
String s1 = "act";
for(char c :s1.toCharArray())
     System.out.println(s1.indexOf(c)+1);
```